# I need to list all records in Route53 based on TTL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have hosted zone with more than 10000 records would like to list out all records which have TTL value more than 300. Can some one please help me to build query using list-resource-record-set?

```
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id XXXXXXXXXXXX --profile MYACCOUNT --max-items 8000 --query "ResourceRecordSets[?ResourceRecords[?Value[?TTL > '300']]]"
```

````
    "ResourceRecordSets": [
         {
            "ResourceRecords": [
                {
                    "Value": "172.18.0.156"
                }
            ], 
            "Type": "A", 
            "Name": "172-18-0-156.example.com.", 
            "TTL": 86400
        }, 
        {
            "ResourceRecords": [
                {
                    "Value": "172.18.0.162"
                }
            ], 
            "Type": "A", 
            "Name": "172-18-0-162.example.com.", 
            "TTL": 200
        }, 
        {
            "ResourceRecords": [
                {
                    "Value": "172.18.0.165"
                }
            ], 
            "Type": "A", 
            "Name": "172-18-0-165.example.com.", 
            "TTL": 86400
        }, 
        {
            "ResourceRecords": [
                {
                    "Value": "172.18.0.207"
                }
            ], 
            "Type": "A", 
            "Name": "172-18-0-207.example.com.", 
            "TTL": 86400
        }
    ]
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

To do it using AWS cli you only need one `?` and the rest of the info comes with it:

```
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id <hosted zone id> --query 'ResourceRecordSets[?TTL >= `300`]'
```

To do it using jq:

```
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id <hosted zone id> |jq -r '.ResourceRecordSets[]| select (.TTL >= 300) '
```

**Resources**

[JMESPath](http://jmespath.org/)

Comment: Thank you very much.  Would you mind to let me know what is the worng with below  command ? ```aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id  XXXXXXX --profile XXXXXXXX --max-items 8000  --query  "ResourceRecordSets[?TTL > `300`]"``` for some reasons this is not working . i got ```Bad value for --query ResourceRecordSets[?TTL > ]: invalid token: Parse error at column 26, token "]" (RBRACKET), for expression:``` error

Comment: Try using single quotes instead of double quotes . route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id XXXXXXX --profile XXXXXXXX --max-items 8000 --query 'ResourceRecordSets[?TTL > `300`]'

Comment: Thanks for all your help.